# How to access container from different host on same network when using macvlan driver

Tags: docker, docker-network

I've created my macvlan network as follows:

```
docker network create -d macvlan -o parent=eth0 \
--subnet 192.168.1.0/24 \
--gateway 192.168.1.1 \
--ip-range 192.168.1.192/27 \
--aux-address 'host=192.168.1.223' \
 mynet
```

I run my container as follows:

```
docker run --name nginx -d --net mynet nginx
```

The container's IP is 192.168.1.192

I have two hosts that can ping each other both ways:

Host A: 192.168.1.98 (where Docker engine is running)

Host B: 192.168.1.6

Because macvlan by definition doesn't allow host-to-container communication, I have created a sub-interface as follows to allow this communication:

```
ip link add mynet-shim link eth0 type macvlan  mode bridge

ip addr add 192.168.1.223/32 dev mynet-shim

ip link set mynet-shim up

ip route add 192.168.1.192/27 dev mynet-shim
```

I'm able to access the container from host A as when I run:

`curl 192.168.1.192:80`, I receive the nginx default html

I'm also able to ping the container from host A.

When I run `docker logs nginx`, it says:

`192.168.1.223 - - [02/Nov/2018:16:19:32 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "curl/7.29.0" "-"`

So it is working with the `mynet-shim` sub-interface.

However, I'm unable to access the container from host B as both the `curl` and `ping` commands to the container fail from host B, even though it's in the same subnet as host A and the container

Is there any additional configuration that I may have missed on host B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was VMWare's network settings.

On VMWare ESXi 6.5 (client version 1.2.3):

1. Click "Networking" on the left hand pane
2. Click "Security"
3. Choose "Accept" for "Promiscuous mode", "MAC address changes" and "Forged transmits"
4. Save

After this, I was able to access the container from a different host on the same network (i.e Host B)